# How can I minimize a child dialog to the task bar in an MFC application?

Tags: mfc, dialog, minimize

I open a child dialog from a parent dialog. Among the child dialog properties I enabled the "Minimize" property. But if click the "Minimize" button, then the child dialog minimizes to the left corner of the screen instead of the Windows task bar. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 5):

Your child dialog must have an extended style containing [`WS_EX_APPWINDOW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/61fe4bte.aspx) (in addition to being a top-level window).

Comment: Thanks.
It works
ModifyStyleEx(0, WS_EX_APPWINDOW);
put the above function in the OnInitDialog() of Child Dialog.

Comment: If it fixes your issue, you may want to vote me up and accept the answer! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the "child" dialog has to be a top-level dialog if you want it to have a presence on the taskbar.

In other words, when creating your child dialog set the parent to NULL or to GetDesktopWindow().  I guess it depends on how your child dialog is being created, though.

It would help if you included the code you're using to create the child dialog.